# socket.io DYNAMIC namespaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, namespaces

I am trying to have my app work with multiple namespaces.

I am creating new namespaces based on the parameters of the route I get passed to the server. Example:

```
var nsp = io.of('/');
var className;

app.post('/class/:classID',function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
   className = req.params.classID;
   nsp = io.of('/' + className)

});
```

where nsp is of course the namespace.

Then I have my socket.io code in which I say:

```
nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
...
...
```

However, the code is not waiting until I get to the app.post route. It is automatically connecting to the default namespace ('/') as I declared it initially.

And the app does not work because on my client code I connect to a specific namespace (not relevant for this) but then the server is connecting to the default one.

What I want is for the socket.io code to WAIT until I get to the app.post part, set the new nsp variable so that it connects to a specific namespace AND THEN do all the socket.io code

How should i go about and do this? I tried to put my socket.io code INSIDE the app.post route but that didn't seem to work very well.

Comment: You should handle on client when to connect. What is your client code?

Comment: @madox2 on my client I just connect to a specific namespace as soon as the page loads up.. Could I kinda WAIT for that?.. I have an html file then under a script tag i have  var path = window.location.pathname;
 var namespace = path.substring(6);

 socket = io(namespace);

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should work if you just rearrange your code a bit.

```
app.get('/class/:classID',function(req,res){
  className = req.params.classID;   
  nsp = io.of('/' + className)
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

  nsp.on('connection', function(socket) {       
    nsp.emit('welcome', { message: 'Welcome!', id: socket.id });
    nsp.on('i am client', console.log);
  });
});
```

Then in index.html you can:

```
var url = window.location.href;    
classIndex = url.indexOf('class/');
className = url.slice(classIndex + 6);
var socket = io('http://localhost:1337/'+className);

socket.on('welcome', function(data) {
  alert("I am connected to: "+className)
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Apparently there is some sort of issue with namespaces.. I used rooms and solved my problem

Comment: If you still need to utilize namespaces or for anyone else looking at this question I've edited my answer. I was able to make this code work on my server. Note that I used a get instead of a post.